# R: Mutliplier lagrange test (lm.LMtests) : what to put for the listw argument

Tags: r

I want to do a lagrange multiplier test on a panel dataset of the following type:

```
UGA   Date      Sales  Nb_AM   Nb_BX   ......
A     01/2017     1       4       14
A     02/2017     8       5       17
A     03/2017     26      2       24
B     01/2017     3       3       35
B     02/2017     5      10       42
B     03/2017     8      24        2
```

I want to use the following command : lm.LMtests()

However, according to R documentation, I need to put an argument of the
type "listw" in lm.LMtests but I have no idea what to put in my case. Could
you help me?

```
For the moment my code is the following : 

fusion2<-read_excel("C:/Users/david/OneDrive/Bureau/Master data/Mémoire 
data analyst/Bases de données/Fusion/fusion.xlsx")
 

modeleam<-Sales ~ Nb_AM + Nb_BX + 
Total_PdS_sensibilisés_aux_événement_AM + Mails_AM_ouvert + 
Mails_AM_non_ouvert + Total_PdS_sensibilisés_aux_RP_AM + 
Total_PdS_sensibilisés_aux_Staff_AM + Total_PdS_sensibilisés_aux_Congrés_AM 
+ Total_PdS_sensibilisés_aux_Opportunités_AM


mcoam <-lm(modeleam, data=fusion2)

lagrangeam <- lm.LMtests(mcoam, ,test="all")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

when you're in the "matter" it's pretty basic. So this test is crated for spatial statistics and a listw-object is nothing else than a neighbour dependence. That means how strongly one value could potentially be influenced by neighbour values.

For that you need for example a simple feature with geometries of a landscape or a city where you can assign the values to a specific polygon. From this pattern, you can create a neighbourhood and then neighbourhood weights (listw-object).

Small tutorial:

```
library(spdep); library(sf)
#Get your data
shape_and_data <- st_read("your/shape")
#Create your neighbourhood, nb-object
data_nb <- poly2nb(shape_and_data)
#Create the neighbour weights, listw-object
data_listw <- nb2listw(data_nb)
#Calculate
lm.LMtests(lm(...), listw = data_listw, test = "all")
```

This is a really basic example. For creating the neighbourhood (nb-object) you can choose different methods and for the weights (listw) there are also several methods.

Hope it helped a bit,
Loubert